# Generating unique integer ID from two integer id's

Tags: php, algorithm

Given 2 integers a and b (positive). Is there any formula / method for generating unique ID number?

note:  result from f(a,b) and f(b,a) should be the same.Solution should be efficient. No matter it would be a scratch of PHP code or algorithm.

Comment: You could do an MD5 hash using the A and B as salt.

Comment: @MateiMihai that is not unique. If A is 1 and B is 4 the sum is 5. If A is 2 and B is 3 the sum is still 5.

Comment: @SaggingRufus there can be situations when id1=12 id2=14 and id1=14 id2=12 this two cases should have the same I'd and it should work fast on thousands elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for 32-bit numbers (using left shift)

```
Int64Code = Max(a, b) + (Min(a, b) << 32)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it simple and fast)